# Scrollbar not working on certain screensizes

Tags: html, css

On my webpage, https://polemos.io/encyclopedia/arliterum-new-template/, the scrollbar is styled with a class "scrollbar-invisible", with the following code:

```
.scrollbar-invisible::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar-invisible::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar-invisible::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #D62929;
}
```

It works on smaller resolutions (eg. mobile and very very tiny laptop, but not above that).

Could someone help me out? Thank you so much!

Comment: why do you try to style a scrollbar? it‘s easier to use overflow: hidden to prevent scrolling

Comment: because I would still like for them to be able to scroll through it, but the default is not on-brand and not having a scrollbar could make it hard for our a few users to understand it's scrollable